# compare two strings and write output into a csv file using beanshell in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am using the beanshell PostProcesser and comparing two variables and writting output to a csv file but somehow it is now working.Below is my code

```
import org.apache.commons.logging;
import java.lang.String.*;

// using regular expression to get Borderid e.g 1234560
String TOID = vars.get("BOrderID");
// file fath to write defined in user defined variables
String fpath = vars.get("write_file_path");
// orderid to search
String SOID = vars.get("orderID");

String DMN = SOID.equals.(TOID);

if (DMN){

  FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(fpath+"order_Status.csv", true);

  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

  out.write(TOID+","+SOID);

  out.newLine();

  out.flush();

  } else {
   log.info("orders did not match");
 }
```

does anyone know what am i doing wrong as this is not working.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: 2017/04/25 09:38:42 WARN  - jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.commons.logging; import java.lang.String.*;  String TOID = var . . . '' Encountered "(" at line 11, column 26.   i.e on String DMN = SOID.equals.(TOID);

Comment: Use this block `if (SOID.equals("${TOID}") {}`

Comment: it does not work

Comment: Use this implementation `String a="Test1";
String b="Test";
if(a.equals(b)){
 log.info("Matched");
}
else
 log.info("Not a Match");`

Comment: it was a little typo error,working fine now.Thanks.

Comment: Can I post this in the answer? Thanks.

Comment: yeah sure you can

Comment: Done :) Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your BeanShell Post Processor, implement the below code snippet.

```
String a="Test"; 
String b="Test123"; 

if(a.equals(b)) {
    log.info("Matched"); 
} 
else { 
    log.info("Not a Match");
}
```

If `if` statement is true, it will print `Matched`, else `Not a Match`.

[image: Matched]

[image: Not a Match]

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
String DMN = SOID.equals.(TOID);
```

to this:

```
boolean DMN = SOID.equals(TOID);
```

also consider switching to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) as when it comes to high loads Beanshell performance becomes a big question mark. Well-behaved Groovy scripts can be compiled into [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) therefore JSR223 Test Elements will perform much better.

See [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) JMeter User Manual entry and [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details. Groovy is almost fully Java compatible so you can reuse your existing Beanshell code.

Comment: not giving any error but every time it is running else statement even though condition is matching.

Comment: used it if not  if (!DMN){ } then it is only executing if statement for all orders while i see SOID=TOID for some  records and even printing in logs

Comment: jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: 6000008        ---- SOID
    jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: 55689072, 
    jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement:  6000008        ----TOID